# How to compare two shell command output in Makefile?

Tags: shell, if-statement, makefile, conditional-statements

My `Makefile` is:

```
.PHONY: check
check:
        ifneq $(shell echo 123), $(shell echo 123)
                $(error Not equal)
        endif
```

When I run, I've got the error:

```
$ make
Makefile:3: *** Not equal.  Stop.
```

But this should happen only when they're different, but they're not. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ifneq` cannot be indented.  the way you've written it, it's being run via a shell command which means the `$(error)` is being evaluated first by the make command.

i'm guessing you want the `make check` to actually run two commands only when `make check` is invoked, and compare their output.  you can do:

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    if [ "`echo 123`" != "`echo 123`" ]; then \
        echo "Not equal"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [*GNU Make docs*](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html), *Conditional Parts* **cannot** be used to control shell commands at the time of execution, since conditionals control what `make` actually "sees" in the makefile.

So to perform condition during compilation process, shell syntax is preferred, e.g.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash -e
.PHONY: check
check:
  @test "$(shell echo 123)" = "$(shell echo 123)" \
    || { echo Not equal; exit 2; } \
    && { echo Equal; }
```